# Neotree ignore list?

Tags: spacemacs

Like in NERDTREE for vim, is there a way to list certain file types to be ignored (not displayed) by neotree ? for instance:

```
*.cs.meta
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Customize the variable `neo-hidden-regexp-list`

The doc-string is very short:  *"The regexp list matching hidden files."*

The default is `'("^\\." "\\.pyc$" "~$" "^#.*#$" "\\.elc$")`

Modify the list as follows in your `.emacs` file:

```
(setq neo-hidden-regexp-list '("^\\." "\\.cs\\.meta$" "\\.pyc$" "~$" "^#.*#$" "\\.elc$"))
```

Comment: Note that you might need to toggle hidden files with `neo-hidden-files-toggle`, by default bound to `s`.